# How to set syntax keywords dynamically

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight, syntax

I'm trying to highlight the keywords for my c++ project.

So what I've done is to create a file here: `~/.vim/after/syntax/cpp.vim` and put some custom configuration into it.

For example, putting the lines as below can highlight the class name:

```
hi CustomClassName guifg=NONE guibg=NONE guisp=NONE gui=bold ctermfg=lightgreen ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold
syn match cCustomClassName "\(^class\s*\)\@<=\w\+"
hi def link cCustomClassName CustomClassName
```

However, this can only highlight the class name while the class declaration.
 [image]

As you see, the `Test` at the line 8 is highlighted whereas the next `Test` at the line 9 isn't.

In a word, I can set the highlight for the declaration class because I can use the regex to match the keyword `class`. But the codes like the line 9 can't be matched by the regex. It seems that I should use some method to find the codes like the line 9 dynamically and highlight them.

I'm thinking if I can set an array to store all custom class name and highlight them but I don't know how to do it.